# NSTextView / Objective - C

Tags: objective-c, string, nstextview

Currently I am creating an application where I am receiving data from an inputstream. This data is set to an `NSString` pointer output. Currently, I am only able to display the output in a regular `NSTextField` window. My current code only allows for these strings to be displayed once the event hasBytesAvailable is true. Everytime hasBytesAvailable is able to return data from the stream, it replaces the `NSTextField` completely. I can not seem to use the object `NSTextView` properly. I want to set up the `NSTextView` to display the string data as the information is returned from the hasBytesAvailable event is performed. I would like to be able to scroll up and see all the information that is being sent through.

The best example I can think of that relates to this would be a chat server/client where my application would be the client accepting data, but having it all saved in the `NSTextView` window.

Thank you

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

    switch (streamEvent) {

        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Stream opened");
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
            NSLog(@"Has space");
            break;

        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

            if (theStream == inputStream) {

                uint8_t buffer[10000];
                long len;

                while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    if (len > 0) {

                        NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                        NSLog(@"Has Bytes");
                        if (nil != output) {
                            NSLog(@"%@", output);
                            [window setString:output];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            NSLog(@"Error.");
            break;

    }

}
```

Comment: I did not get your question. Can you please explain what you wanted to achieve??

Comment: please provide a meaningful title

Comment: I am gathering bytes from an inputstream. These bytes become buffered into strings. The strings are updated via the [window setString:output]; line. Unfortunately, that deletes the previous Strings that were on the screen. I am trying to format this differently, So I can display the messages received from the inputstream like a chat window would. I am looking for help on how to format an NSTextView to hold all the strings that come through the input stream.

Comment: Thank you, Gabriele. I am new to stack overflow and I will be more specific in the future.